# Infinite nested radicals from Putnam exam 1953

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, nested-radicals

Prove that the following sequence is convergent and find the limit:

$$\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7}}, \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7}}}, ... $$

with $x_{n+2}=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x_{n}}}$.

---

Notice that $$2=\sqrt{7-3}=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+2}}=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+2}}}} $$

$$=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+...}}}}}}$$

Q: Is this proof valid? If not why? Since this is a contest problem and the trick is well known (but not at that time i guess)

I already know the rigorous solution, but this is not my Q.

Comment: That set of statements are true for any finite number of cases, but you cannot make it infinite terms by just putting another equal to; there is no rule that justifies that last step.  Otherwise similarly you could  claim $0=1-1=1-1+1-1+...=1-(1-1)-(1-1)-...=1$ for e.g.

Comment: @Macavity but your example is different, in that case I would write a note that number of 1s and -1s are equal.

Comment: It's certainly convincing, but I think there needs to be some kind of argument that the sequence approaches the same limit as the original one.

Comment: @Arief and that note would also be incorrect, as the number of 1s and -1s are both infinite, there is no "equal" relationship defined except as cardinailty of sets.

Comment: I believe your solution (as is) will only be given 0 or 1 points, esp given that this is A6 of the putnam:  A) Your terms are not the (even) terms of the sequence, B) You ignored the odd terms, so even if the even terms converged you've not shown the sequence converged, C) In some cases, that replacement trick can lead to a non-convergent series. Instead, use that as a guide for what the value should be, then prove convergence directly. (IE The rigorous solution)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to find the limit of the sequence
$$x_0=\sqrt{7},x_1=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7}},x_{n+2}=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x_{n}}}$$

You have a different sequence:
$$x_0=2,x_1=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+2}},x_{n+2}=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x_{n}}}$$
You have a good argument that this sequence is constant, so its limit is $2$.

Your sequence has the same recurrence relation as the given sequence. But why should it necessarily have the same limit? Maybe you can make an additional argument that these two sequences do have the same limiting behavior, but I think that is missing so far.

Also this last "expression" that you have, $\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+...}}}}}}$ is meaningless by itself. In context of your answer, it is the limit of the second sequence above. But the standard interpretation of it would be the limit of the sequence from that Putnam problem. So we can also say there is a problem with giving that expression two meanings and taking them to mean the same thing.

Comment: I know the rigorous solution. But why is the solution above not valid?

Comment: @Arief I added why I think there is a missing element to the argument.

Comment: I just deleted the first part of what I had posted. This second part is more to the point of your question, which I tried to say, but didn't do a good enough job with in my original first paragraph.